# Is possible to have multiple different types of refs for a single attribute in mongoose (mongodb)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongodb with mongoose. And i am wondering if it is possible to have multiple references for an object id attribute in a schema.

I have tried the code underneath and it did not work.

```
const Schema = new Schema({
  refrens: {
      type: ObjectId,

      // this did not work
      ref: [
          "Post",
          "Account"
      ],

      required: true
  }
});
```

I know it is possible to remove the ref attribute (field, key) and then all object ids are valid but i want certain object ids to be valid, the object ids of the Post and Account model.

```
const Schema = new Schema({
  refrens: {
      // This will allow all different types of object ids to be the value
      type: ObjectId,

      required: true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Look like [refPath](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref) is what you need. You can do something like this:

```
const Schema = new Schema({
  refrens: {
    type: ObjectId,
    refPath: 'onModel',
    required: true
  },
  onModel: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ['Post', 'Account']
  }
});
```